# Modify multiple oracle triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a task that involves updating many triggers which are exactly the same query but applied to several different tables. Is there a way to update all these TRIGGERS using a FOR or similar statement? Actually what I need to do is modify the WHEN clause for all this triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use dbms_metadat for this.

for example:

```
declare
  type arr_tab is table of varchar2(30);
  v_arr arr_tab;
  v_trig  clob;
begin
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param( DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 
                    'SQLTERMINATOR', FALSE );

  v_arr := arr_tab('TEST_TRIG', 'TEST2_TRIG'); -- change these triggers.
  for idx in 1..v_arr.count
  loop
    v_trig := dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER',v_arr(idx), user);
    execute immediate regexp_replace(regexp_replace(v_trig, 'ALTER TRIGGER.*', ''), 'WHEN ([^\)]*\))', 'WHEN (1=1)', 1, 1, 'mi');
  end loop;
end;
/
```

the `'WHEN ([^\)]*\))', 'WHEN (1=1)'` part replaces the `WHEN` clause with (in my case) `WHEN (1=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dba_triggers to extract the text of the trigger into CREATE or replace statements. But due to some of the columns being LONG datatype you will have trouble extracting them as VARCHAR2.  This can be resolved by using Tom Kytes package which is lost somewhere on the oracle site. I include my own version which you may have to modify to meet your needs.

Run the select, insert your when clause and then run the create or replace statements.

This won't work due to the trigger_body being a long datatype

```
select 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER '|| description
||trigger_body
from dba_triggers
where owner = 'Your schema'
```

but this should work if your triggers are not more than 4000 characters

```
select 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER '|| description
    || ADMIN.LONG_HELP.SUBSTR_OF('select trigger_body from dba_triggers where    trigger_name = :0',
1,4000,'0',dt.trigger_name)
from dba_triggers dt
where owner = 'YourSchema';


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ADMIN.LONG_HELP
   /******************************************************************************
      NAME:       LONG_HELP
      PURPOSE:    Read fields of type long.  (commonly found in data dictionary)

      REVISIONS:
      Ver        Date        Author           Description
      ---------  ----------  ---------------  ------------------------------------
      1.0        10/27/2011             1. Created this package. based on Tom Kyte's column here
      http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:839298816582
      note  that it only retrieves the first 4000 characters of any LONG column
      USAGE in a WHERE
      INSTR(
      ADMIN.LONG_HELP.SUBSTR_OF('SELECT text from all_views where view_name =:o ',
      1,4000,'o',m2.obj_name),m1.FK_ID) > 0

   ******************************************************************************/

   --AUTHID CURRENT_USER 
   --removed to get around ORA-29470: Effective userid or roles are not the same as when cursor was parsed
   --restrict usage to admin schema for Oracle 11g

AS
   FUNCTION substr_of (p_query   IN VARCHAR2,
                       p_from    IN NUMBER,
                       p_for     IN NUMBER,
                       p_name1   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_bind1   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_name2   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_bind2   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_name3   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_bind3   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_name4   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_bind4   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL )
      RETURN VARCHAR2;
END LONG_HELP;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ADMIN.LONG_HELP
AS
   g_cursor   NUMBER := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
   g_query    VARCHAR2 (32765);


   PROCEDURE bind_variable (p_name IN VARCHAR2, p_value IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF (p_name IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
         DBMS_SQL.bind_variable (g_cursor, p_name, p_value);
      END IF;
   END BIND_VARIABLE;



   FUNCTION substr_of (p_query   IN VARCHAR2,
                       p_from    IN NUMBER,
                       p_for     IN NUMBER,
                       p_name1   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_bind1   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_name2   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_bind2   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_name3   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_bind3   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_name4   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
                       p_bind4   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL )
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   AS
   /******************************************************************************
   NAME:       LONG_HELP.SUBSTR_OF
   PURPOSE:    CONVERT long data fields into VARCHAR2
   WHOSE DATA IS CHANGED: none
   WHAT USES THIS:
   WHERE ARE THE RESOURCES NEEDED:

******************************************************************************/
      l_buffer       VARCHAR2 (4000);
      l_buffer_len   NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      IF (NVL (p_from, 0) <= 0)
      THEN
         raise_application_error (-20002,
                                  'From must be >= 1 (positive numbers)');
      END IF;

      IF (NVL (p_for, 0) NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 4000)
      THEN
         raise_application_error (-20003, 'For must be between 1 and 4000');
      END IF;


      IF (p_query <> g_query OR g_query IS NULL)
      THEN
         IF (UPPER (TRIM (NVL (p_query, 'x'))) NOT LIKE 'SELECT%')
         THEN
            raise_application_error (-20001, 'This must be a select only');
         END IF;

         DBMS_SQL.parse (g_cursor, p_query, DBMS_SQL.native);
         g_query := p_query;
      END IF;

      bind_variable (p_name1, p_bind1);
      bind_variable (p_name2, p_bind2);
      bind_variable (p_name3, p_bind3);
      bind_variable (p_name4, p_bind4);

      DBMS_SQL.define_column_long (g_cursor, 1);

      IF (DBMS_SQL.execute_and_fetch (g_cursor) > 0)
      THEN
         DBMS_SQL.column_value_long (g_cursor,
                                     1,
                                     p_for,
                                     p_from - 1,
                                     l_buffer,
                                     l_buffer_len);
      END IF;

      RETURN l_buffer;
   END substr_of;
END LONG_HELP;
/
```